# how to know the number of iterables in a generator in python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have the following code

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> def test_yield(lst):
...     for el in lst:
...        yield el
... 
>>> var = test_yield(x)
>>> var.next()
'a'
>>> var.next()
'b'
>>> var.next()
'c'
>>> var.next()
'd'
>>> var.next()
'e'
```

how can I know the length of iterables (in this case the length of the list) from the generator.
In my real case, I do not have the exact list. I have that from generator. simply put, I would like  to know the number of iterables in var after my second var.next() or so.

Comment: couldnt you keep a running count as you added them to your set?

Comment: I want to know how much is left to be added to the set, for which I should know the length I started with, then having a counter as I add them, would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can not. Iterators can be infinite.

```
def test_yield():
    count = 1
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield count
```

Comment: They can also be such that the only way to figure out how long they are is to enumerate them completely, even though they are finite.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your iterator is not infinite (see @unutbu's answer), you can put put the results in a list first, and then get the length:

```
stuff = list(test_yield(x))
print(len(stuff))
```

Comment: If I turn into a list, then there is no purpose of using generators in the first instance right? when the lists are huge, it is better to get them through generators as they do not occupy much memory

Comment: @user1988876 That's basically correct, but a function writer may not know how their data will be used, so it's generally good practice to return iterators from functions, and let their callers convert to a list if necessary.